# How to bind the result of a method instead of a property of an object of a custom class in a Windows Universal App C#

Tags: c#, class, win-universal-app

I have a class with some properties and methods and I bind an ObservableCollection of objects of this class to a list view in a Windows Universal App.

However a lot of the things I want to display on each item of this list are properties of the class which are derived from other properties: for example I might have a Boolean about the object and then for the UI two colours representing true and false. This Boolean may may also the result of calculations between multiple float properties of the object

My question is can I bind the result of a method in the class to save me from calculating the other properties separately and having properties for those things?

I've looked into converters but they look like they operate on a single property and here I need to be able to act on multiple properties

Comment: Whats wrong with a calculated property? - Show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool MyBool {get; set;}

    public Color MyColor()
    {
        if (this.MyBool) return Colors.Green;
        else return Colors.Red;
    }
}
```

And you want to bind `MyColor`, you could just make it a readonly property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool MyBool {get; set;}
    public Color MyBoolColor { get { return this.MyBool ? Colors.Green : Colors.Red; }
}
```

You then proceed to bind and use `MyBoolColor` as you wish. Basically, what you now have as methods beceome the `get` part of read-only properties.

This is of course a very short proof-of-concept which might need to be adapted to your actual code.